# Set up client ceritficate file path for external SMTP server in GitLab

Tags: smtp, ssl-certificate, gitlab

Is it possible to set up GitLab to use external SMTP server which configured to accept connection only with client SSL certificate?
I have no idea which parameter can I use in GitLab smtp configuration to setup client certificate file path. I tryed put my certificate to `/usr/local/etc/ssl` and use parameter

```
ca_path: "/usr/local/etc/ssl"
```

but without success. SMTP server says

> NOQUEUE: abort: TLS from unknown[192.168.0.11]: No client certificate
>   presented